# Can't Access Index of Associative Array php

Tags: php, json

I'm sending my posted data to the server as a block of JSON data due to its size. Once it arrives, I decode it using `json_decode` and then go about my business. The problem I've run into is I can't access values at indexes. When I `print_r` the array it shows everything, but trying to echo the value at an index shows nothing. Why doesn't the echo work? Here's what I'm trying:

```
$content = json_decode($_POST['result']);

print_r($content); //works

echo $content["rowCount"]; //doesn't work
```

Here's what `print_r($content);` prints out:

> stdClass Object ( [prodName] => [company] => [runTime] => [adLine]
>   => [vintage] => [agency] => [vimeo] => [notes] => [displayOrder] => [infoId] => [prodName1] => test [company1] => test [runTime1] => 0
>   [adLine1] => [vintage1] => 0 [agency1] => [vimeo1] =>
>   https://vimeo.com/ [notes1] => [displayOrder1] =>
>   0 [infoId1] => 339 [rowCount] => 1 )

Comment: _trying to echo the value at an index shows nothing..._ Because there is no array but objects

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try passing `true` as the second argument to the `json_decode()` function:

```
$content = json_decode($_POST['result'], true);
```

Or ... access the data as an object:

```
echo $content->rowCount;
```

Answer (score 2):

By default, `json_decode` will convert it into a stdClass object. If you need an associative array, pass `true` as the 2nd argument.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php

```
<?php

$content = json_decode($_POST['result'], true);
...
```

Answer (score 1):

The print_r out is self-explanatory. You see the print_r output says it is a stdClass Object. So, you need to access them using  $content->key_name.
I am not sure if you have the array in proper format which was used to json_encode.